# DNS servers on Local Area Connection should include the loopback address, but not as first entry issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, active-directory

We have a small network that doesn't currently take advantage of IPv6, and I am in the process of introducing a windows 2008 server into the domain. I'd like it to eventually become our primary dns server. Our network is currently composed of a single Windows 2003 R2 domain controller.

After setting the Windows 2008 server up as a DNS server, I am getting the message,

> DNS servers on Local Area Connection
>   should include the loopback address,
>   but not as first entry.

The IPv4 address is set up correctly with the primary DNS server as the first entry and the loopback address as the second, but I have never worked with IPv6 before, and the Windows server 2003 server doesn't have a IPv6 address (and I wouldn't mind leaving it that way for as long as possible - if it ain't broke don't fix it). Hence, the IPv6 configuration on the 2008 server only contains the loopback address in the DNS configuration of the network adapter.

My question then, has three parts:

1. Can (should?) I disable IPv6 on the 2008 server, or barring that,
2. Will the current setup affect Active Directory replication, or
3. Is it strongly encouraged to set up the 2003 server with an IPv6 address despite the size of our network (and how should I go about doing that?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the current setup will not affect AD replication, it is absolutely safe to disable IPv6 on your servers, and I think you should.

Comment: To clarify.. DNS will prefer an IPv6 server if available, but lookups for either v4 or v6 will work just fine no matter which protocol you're using to communicate with the DNS server.  Your IPv6 setting likely got in there automatically during the DNS role installation, and that is effectively taking precedence over your IPv4 DNS server specifications.  Personally, I'm not terribly offended by waiting for a DNS timeout during AD's startup, but it's not best practice.  Setting your IPv6 adapter to not have hardcoded DNS at all will be just as effective as disabling it.

Comment: I have to say it: I love your avatar, SpacemanSpiff! As a note, leaving IPv6 enabled and removing the IPv6 loopback address from the DNS servers also removes the error from the Best Practices Analyzer.

Comment: There is no reason to disable IPv6, also you hsould verify that you are running SP1

Comment: Honestly Jim I usually disable because of the extra information I'm having to sort through when I'm running commands like ipconfig. If I'm not using it, I don't need it running.